# Get Model associated with corresponding View in HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-3

My View inherits `Models.MyModel`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Something.Master" Inherits="Models.MyModel>" %>
```

I need a property `Model.Something` to be available in a `HtmlHelper` method when I call it from this view.

```
<%= Html.CustomHelper(...) %>
```

Is there any way to access this? Maybe via `ViewContext` or `ViewDataDictionary`?

I do not want to explicitly pass `Model.SessionKey` for each helper I call. Is there any approach that I missed? Or is this impossible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My approach to this would be to have the all the models that you want to use with this helper implement an interface that defines their common properties.  The ViewData property on the HtmlHelper object has a Model property (of type `object`).  Inside your helper, you can cast this as the interface type.  Assuming that it is non-null at that point, i.e., actually not null and of the correct type, you can then use the common properties.

```
public static string CustomerHelper( this HtmlHelper helper, ... )
{
    var model = helper.ViewData.Model as ISessionModel;

    var sessionKey = model.SessionKey;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Similarly you can do this:

```
public static string CustomerHelper( this HtmlHelper helper, ... )
{
    ISessionModel model = helper.ViewData.Model;

    var sessionKey = model.SessionKey;

    ...
}
```

The only difference is that you don't have to do a cast....

Comment: Surely this doesn't compile, you're *implicitly* casting `object` to `ISessionModel`?